# how to display values related to items in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

let us consider when we filter batch and area we get items
for example let us consider batch = 1000 and area = A01 and when filtering the Items tables with these batch and area as a result we get 3 items

```
id      item_name       season_support                   

1        small tree     [u'Winter', u'Year round']       

2        medium tree    [u'Spring', u'Autumn']

3        big tree       [u'Summer', u'Rainy']
```

Now while printing in the pdf let us consider my index.html as

```
 {% for item in items %}
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Item id - {{ item.id }}</td>
           <td>Item name -  {{item.item_name}} </td>
           <td>Season support - {{ item.season_support }} </td>
           
        </tr>
    
    </table>
```

now please help to write views.py where i can print the season_support that are related those items only

Comment: `<table>` needs to go outside `{% for item in items %}` (and `{% endfor %}` before </table>)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get a list of values returned for `season_support` as in your example, you can simply do the example below to render your values.

```
<td>Season support - {{ item.season_support | join(', ') }} </td>
```

Comment: if i use {{ item.season_support | join:', '}} i am getting in this way [, u, ', W, i, n, t, e, r, ', ,, , u, ', Y, e, a, r, , r, o, u, n, d, ', ]